# Unable to cast generic object

Tags: c#, generics, covariance

I have the following conceptual model:

```
public interface IFoo<out T>
{
    T Data { get; }
}

public struct Foo<T> : IFoo<T>
{
    public Foo(T data) : this()
    {
        Data = data;
    }

    public T Data { get; private set; }
}

public class FooService<T> 
{
    ...

    public Foo<T> Get(string id)
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

Then I try to use it in a way that conceptually is equivalent to this:

```
// Create and register a few FooService instances
ServiceLocator.Register(new FooService<DateTime>(), "someServiceId");
ServiceLocator.Register(new FooService<double?>(), "anotherServiceId");

// Retrieve a particular FooService instance and call the Get method
var fooService = (FooService<object>)ServiceLocator.Get("someServiceId");
var foo = fooService.Get("someFooId");
```

I want to use the Get() method on a FooService instance - no matter what type the selected FooService instance returns. However, this code results in the following exception:

> Unable to cast object of type 'WindowsFormsApplication7.FooService`1[System.DateTime]' to type 'WindowsFormsApplication7.FooService`1[System.Object]'.

Any suggestions on how to solve this problem would be greately appreciated.

You could argue, why I made the FooService generic in the first place. However, this is done to secure type safety in a type safe environment. In this particular case, though, the FooService shall be used in a Web API controller to serve various types of Foo. It shall return a response with Foo of T disregarding the type of T.

Comment: you also need an interface IFooServive<out T> whence your cast is (IFooService<object>)  whence your FooService<referenceType> can be an IFooService<object>, hwoever as pointed out below this wont work for value types.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think you have already given the correct answer:

`FooService<double?>` can never be casted to `FooService<object>`, and
`FooService<DateTime>` can never be casted to `FooService<object>`.

Using covariance or contravariance does not change that. The page https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997386.aspx states: `Value types also do not support variance.` And since `double?` and `DateTime` are value types, this can never work.

Comment: double? isn't a value type. It's Nullable<double>, as well he can use DateTime? instead of DateTime.

Comment: @WojciechKulik, `Nullable<T>` is a `struct`

Comment: @haim770 oh... yes, you're right, my mistake :-). Anyway this can be helpful: [Creating Variant Generic Interfaces](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997386.aspx)

Comment: @haim770 Thanks, I get it. But any suggestions on a workaround for obtaining my goal? "I want to use the Get() method on a FooService instance - no matter what type the selected FooService instance returns"

Comment: @Lars: Do the solution HAVE to be a generic solution? I mean... why not use a non-generic interface `IFoo` with property `object Data`?

Comment: as I stated in the question itself, that is a very legitimate question. However, this model is part of a library generally used in type safe environments, so it is generic. I just try to use it in a http controller where the type safety is a burden

Comment: @Lars: WHAT is very legitimate? I do not understand what you mean.

Comment: your question about why the interfaces/services are generic is legitimate. But they are (because they are taken from a library)

Answer (score 2):

If possible, you could adjust your model like this:

```
public interface IFoo
{
    object Data { get; }
}

public interface IFoo<T> : IFoo
{
    new T Data { get; }
}

public class Foo<T> : IFoo<T>
{
    public Foo(T data) { Data = data; }
    public T Data { get; private set; }
    object IFoo.Data { get { return Data; } }
}

public interface IFooService
{
    IFoo Get(string id);
}

public interface IFooService<T> : IFooService
{
    new IFoo<T> Get(string id);
}

public class FooService<T> : IFooService<T>
{
    public IFoo<T> Get(string id) { return null; }
    IFoo IFooService.Get(string id) { return Get(id); }
}
```

which would enable you to do

```
ServiceLocator.Register(new FooService<DateTime>(), "someServiceId");
ServiceLocator.Register(new FooService<double?>(), "anotherServiceId");

// Retrieve a particular FooService instance and call the Get method
IFooService fooService = (IFooService)ServiceLocator.Get("someServiceId");
IFoo foo = fooService.Get("someFooId");
object data = foo.Data;
```

Comment: That might be a good alternative that I will consider. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I made an example that actually works for reference types, but - as stated by @Martin - can never work for value types, as they do not support variance. The `where T : class` constraint ensures that only reference types are accepted.

```
public interface IFoo<out T> where T : class
{
     T Data { get; }
}

public struct Foo<T> : IFoo<T> where T : class
{
    public Foo(T data) : this()
    {
        Data = data;
    }

    public T Data { get; private set; }
}

public interface IFooService<out T> where T : class 
{
    IFoo<T> Get(string id);
}

public class FooService<T> : IFooService<T> where T : class
{
    public IFoo<T> Get(string id)
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
ServiceLocator.Register(new FooService<Bar>(), "ServiceId");
// OK because Bar is a reference type 
var fooService = (IFooService<object>)ServiceLocator.Get("ServiceId"); 
var foo = fooService.Get("FooId");
```